# The function corresponding to this curve

Tags: analysis, functions

What is the function corresponding to a curve which looks like the following:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
y=50-49\sqrt{1-x^2}
$$
$ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: Good guess. I was thinking of $(7x)^2+1$ but yours captures the vertical tangent at $x=1$